# Convert SQL query to NHibernate criteria query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nhibernate

I want to do the following in nhibernate. I am using criteria query on nhibernate. Does criteria query support the equivalent of this sql statement ?

```
select * from table where tableid in (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the QueryOver interface:

```
session.QueryOver<MappedType>().AndRestrictionOn(m => m.tableid).IsIn(new int[] { 1, 2 , 3 , 4 }).List();
```

or

```
session.QueryOver<MappedType>().Where(m=> m.tableid.IsIn(new int[] { 1, 2 , 3 , 4 })).List();
```

or with the Criteria interface:

```
session.CreateCriteria<MappedType>().Add(Expression.In("tableId", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } ) ).List<MappedType>();
```

Answer (score 4):

As simple as:

```
CurrentSession
  .CreateCriteria( typeof(MappedType) )
  .Add( Expression.In("MappedType.MappedId", new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 } ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does, ie:

```
ISession session = GetSession();
var criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Product));

var ids= new[] {1,2,3};
criteria.Add(new InExpression("Id", ids));

var products = criteria.List<Product>();
```